# Numerical Methods - Gradient method

Tags: numerical-methods, gradient-descent

Consider the (unpreconditioned) gradient method for the solution of a linear system $A\underline{x} = \underline{b}$.

(a) Show that the acceleration parameter $\alpha_{k}$ in the gradient method is the unique solution to the minimisation problem: $\alpha_{k} = arg min \Phi(\underline{x}^k +\alpha\underline{r}^k)$, where $\Phi(\underline{y})=\frac{1}{2}\underline{y}^TA\underline{y}-\underline{y}^T\underline{b}$ denotes the energy of the system $A\underline{x}=\underline{b}$.

(b) Show that the residuals in the gradient method satisfy $(\underline{r}^{k+1},\underline{r}^k)=0$ for each $k$.

(c) Give a geometric interpretation of the gradient method.

I attempted the first part of this question as follows:

$\Phi(\underline{x}^k + \alpha\underline{r}^k) = \frac{1}{2}(\underline{x}^k+\alpha\underline{r}^k)^TA(\underline{x}^k + \alpha\underline{r}^k)-(\underline{x}^k + \alpha\underline{r}^k)^T\underline{b}$.

And using the fact that $\alpha_k = \frac{||\underline{r}^k||^2_{2}}{||\underline{r}^k||^2_{A}}$, I said:

$argmin(\frac{1}{2}(\underline{x}^k+\alpha\underline{r}^k)^TA(\underline{x}^k + \alpha\underline{r}^k)-(\underline{x}^k + \alpha\underline{r}^k)^T\underline{b})=\frac{||\underline{r}^k||^2_{2}}{||\underline{r}^k||^2_{A}}$.

I'm not sure whether this is even the right approach. As for the other parts, I'm completely clueless. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify the gradient method you are referring to? I am assuming $x^k = x^{k-1} - \alpha_k\nabla f(x^k)$.

Comment: Also can you explicit how is $\alpha_k$ defined? What is the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_A$? What are the assumptions on $A$?

Comment: The gradient method I am referring to is this: 
$x^{k+1}=x^k + \alpha_kr^k$, where $r^k = b - Ax^k$ (the residual).
As for $\alpha_k$, this is chosen in a way to minimise the error $||e^{k+1}||_A$.
And the $||.||_A$ is the A-weighted norm $||v||_A = \sqrt{v^TAv}$. 
As far as what we were told in the question, there aren't any assumptions on A.

Comment: For the norm to actually be a norm, you need $A$ to be definite positive then. Can you explicit what is $\lVert e^{k+1} \rVert_A$? How did you get that it is equal to $\frac{\lVert r^k\rVert_2^2}{\lVert r^k\rVert_A^2}$?